# Open Marketplace from Windows Phone 7 browser

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a way to open the Windows Phone 7 marketplace from a page being viewed in the mobile browser.

In an WP7 app I can do this:

```
MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
marketplaceDetailTask.ContentIdentifier = "3cc99ca6-f0e6-df11-a844-00237de2db9e";
marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
```

On the desktop I can do this in a web page:

http://social.zune.net/redirect?type=phoneApp&id=3cc99ca6-f0e6-df11-a844-00237de2db9e

Is there a way to do this from a web page in the mobile browser?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The URL format to launch Marketplace on the phone when a user clicks on a URL is:

**zune://navigate/?appID={app guid}**

So for your app that would be:

**zune://navigate/?appID=3cc99ca6-f0e6-df11-a844-00237de2db9e**

If you want this hyperlinked in the browser simply wrap with a href tag.

```
<a href="zune://navigate/?appID=3cc99ca6-f0e6-df11-a844-00237de2db9e">Download Marketplace Search</a>
```

Comment: This is the answer the OP is looking for. Works both on the device and the emulator.

Answer (score 2):

The browser on Windows Phone 7 emulator doesn't support direct (type -> navigate) application navigation. What Omar is showing won't work **if you type it up** in the emulator because there are internal restrictions as to what protocols can called directly, and `zune` is not one of the supported protocols.

It will, however, work from the email application and the browser as a link.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your answer. I assumed based on the question that he is trying to make it possible for a user to click on a URL in his Marketplace Search application so that users can install the application from Marketplace.

Comment: I think that's what he meant. Basically what I'm saying is that you need to reference the URL from an external source and not directly.

Answer (score 1):

The rules for marketplace links changed and the zune:// links are no longer valid.
The proper format for the deep link is:

```
http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=the_app_id
```

The appid is the guid assigned to your app and can be found on the details screen for your app in the app hub.

The advantage of this format is that it is a direct link to the app in the user's localized marketplace.

On a Windows Phone, this link opens the web browser, which immediately launches the marketplace app.