# Creating web links that will open a website, iOS, Android or Win8 app depending on device

Tags: android, ios, mobile, hyperlink

Does anyone have any suggestions for the best way to create a web link that, depending on the device the user is browsing with will direct them to a website (for laptop/desktops), the App Store (for iOS devices), the Play Store (for Android devices) or the Win8 store, with a default to the website if device type is unknown?

At the moment, the best option seems to be to direct users to a website exclusively, with smart banners that will show a link to the App Store on relevant devices using the following code in the site header:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```

But this is inelegant and can be missed by site visitors plus the additional step leads to a high dropoff. Any suggestions or thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather delayed reply but here goes:

1. Detect which OS is being used using Javascript code. [Link](http://blog.justin.kelly.org.au/simple-javascript-mobile-os-detector/)
2. Change the hyperlink based on whether it is an iPhone Android or Windows.
3. If its iPhone use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store), if its Android use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922762/open-link-of-google-play-store-in-mobile-version-android) and for Windows use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993895/open-marketplace-from-windows-phone-7-browser)

Hope that helped!